# Coverage probability problem for moving block bootstrap

Tags: r, time-series, regression, simulation

I applying moving block bootstrap (MBB) to a regression model using time series data. When I calculated the coverage probability of the estimators derived from the MBB the outcomes were anomalous except one coefficient (coeffcient for x1 which was set to be a continuous variable). Given that MBB is a well-establish method (see https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.713.1262&rep=rep1&type=pdf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)), I was wondering if there is something wrong with my code. I appreciate any input!

```
set.seed(63)
#create a function to generate time series data
tsfunc3 <- function (size=30, ar=0.7) {
  ar.epsilon <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = 0.7), n = size, sd=2)
  x1=rnorm(size)
  x2=sample(1:5, size, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2))
  x3=rbinom(size, 1, 0.5)
  y=as.numeric(5 + 0.25*x1 + 0.4*x2 + 0.8*x3 + ar.epsilon) #A combination of continuous 
                                                           #predictor x1, ordinal predictor
                                                           #x2 and binary predictor x3
  data.frame(time=1:size, x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3, y=y)}

#A time series
tdat <- tsfunc3()

# Block length derived from the data based on the approach proposed by Politis & White 
#(2003): 
b <- 3
#Initial values
#blocks=tdat[1:3,c(2,3,4,5)]
n <- 30
#A sequence of blocks
blocks <- lapply(seq_len(n-b+1), function(i) seq(i, i+b-1))

#MBB for intercept estimator
IntMbb <- function() { 
  take.blocks <- sample(1:28,10,replace=TRUE)
  newdat <- tdat[unlist(blocks[take.blocks]),]
  x1 <- unlist(newdat["x1"])
  x2 <- unlist(newdat["x2"])
  x3 <- unlist(newdat["x3"])
  y <- unlist(newdat["y"])
  regmbb <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
  confint(regmbb, "(Intercept)", level = 0.95)
}

#MBB for x1 coefficient estimator
B1Mbb <- function() { 
  take.blocks <- sample(1:28,10,replace=TRUE)
  newdat <- tdat[unlist(blocks[take.blocks]),]
  x1 <- unlist(newdat["x1"])
  x2 <- unlist(newdat["x2"])
  x3 <- unlist(newdat["x3"])
  y <- unlist(newdat["y"])
  regmbb <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
  confint(regmbb, "x1", level = 0.95)
}

#MBB for x2 coefficient estimator
B2Mbb <- function() { 
  take.blocks <- sample(1:28,10,replace=TRUE)
  newdat <- tdat[unlist(blocks[take.blocks]),]
  x1 <- unlist(newdat["x1"])
  x2 <- unlist(newdat["x2"])
  x3 <- unlist(newdat["x3"])
  y <- unlist(newdat["y"])
  regmbb <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
  confint(regmbb, "x2", level = 0.95)
}

#MBB for x3 coefficient estimator
B3Mbb <- function() { 
  take.blocks <- sample(1:28,10,replace=TRUE)
  newdat <- tdat[unlist(blocks[take.blocks]),]
  x1 <- unlist(newdat["x1"])
  x2 <- unlist(newdat["x2"])
  x3 <- unlist(newdat["x3"])
  y <- unlist(newdat["y"])
  regmbb <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)
  confint(regmbb, "x3", level = 0.95)
}

#Replications
set.seed(47) 
R <- 100
int.mbb <- replicate(R, IntMbb(), simplify=FALSE)
b1.mbb <- replicate(R, B1Mbb(), simplify=FALSE)
b2.mbb <- replicate(R, B2Mbb(), simplify=FALSE)
b3.mbb <- replicate(R, B3Mbb(), simplify=FALSE)

#Calculate coverage probability for intercept estimator
int.ci <- t(sapply(int.mbb, function(x, y) x[grep(y, rownames(x)), ], "Intercept"))
sum(int.ci[,"2.5 %"] <=5 & 5 <= int.ci[,"97.5 %"])/R
[1] 0.34

#Calculate coverage probability for x1 coefficient estimator
int.ci <- t(sapply(b1.mbb, function(x, y) x[grep(y, rownames(x)), ], "x1"))
sum(int.ci[,"2.5 %"] <=0.25 & 0.25 <= int.ci[,"97.5 %"])/R
[1] 0.9

#Calculate coverage probability for x2 coefficient estimator
int.ci <- t(sapply(b2.mbb, function(x, y) x[grep(y, rownames(x)), ], "x2"))
sum(int.ci[,"2.5 %"] <=0.4 & 0.4 <= int.ci[,"97.5 %"])/R
[1] 0.38

#Calculate coverage probability for x3 coefficient estimator
int.ci <- t(sapply(b3.mbb, function(x, y) x[grep(y, rownames(x)), ], "x3"))
sum(int.ci[,"2.5 %"] <=0.8 & 0.8 <= int.ci[,"97.5 %"])/R
[1] 0.33
```

As you can see, only the coverage probability for x1 coefficient estimator is ok. So anything wrong about my code? Or does this have something to do with MBB itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really evaluating the coverage probabilities for the bootstrap.  You need to build the confidence interval from the bootstrapped statistics, not making confidence intervals from the parametric models run on the bootstrapped samples.  Here's how I would do it.

First, we can generate the data:

```
set.seed(45301)
b <- 3
n <- 30
nblocks <- ceiling(n/b)
blocks <- lapply(seq_len(n-b+1), function(i) seq(i, i+b-1))

#A time series
tdat <- tsfunc3(size=n, ar=.7)
```

Next, we could write a function that we will bootstrap.  This function generates the bootstrap sample, runs the regression and saves the coefficients.

```
bsfun <- function(data, blocks){
  samp.data <- data[sample(1:length(blocks), length(blocks), replace=TRUE), ]
  mod <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=samp.data)
  coef(mod)
}
```

Next, we can run the function lots of times. Note that to generate a reliable 95% percentile confidence interval, you should have in the neighborhood of 1500-2500 bootstrap statistics.  The farther the quantile you're trying to characterize is in the tails, the more bootstrap samples you need.  So, the code below generates a single set of bootstrap coefficients:

```
out <- t(replicate(1000, bsfun(data=tdat, blocks=blocks)))
```

From this one set of bootstrap statistics, we can make a single confidence interval.

```
ci1 <- t(apply(out, 2, quantile, probs=c(.025,.975), na.rm=TRUE))
#                   2.5%     97.5%
# (Intercept) -0.3302237 10.258229
# x1          -1.7577214  2.301975
# x2          -0.8016478  2.049435
# x3          -3.0723869  6.190383
```

If you want to investigate the coverage probabilities of these intervals, you wold have to do what I did above, lots of times (we'll do 100, though to get better estimates, you would probably want to do more). We could then write a little function that would evaluate the coverage of one set of estimates:

```
eval_cover <- function(true = c(5,.25,.4, .8), obs){
  out <- as.numeric(obs[,1] < true & obs[,2] > true)
  names(out) <- rownames(obs)
  out 
}
```

Then, you could apply that function to each of the bootstrap confidence intervals you generated.  Using the `rowMeans()` function will get the mean of the coverage 1/0 values, which will be the coverage probability.  In this case, using only 100 intervals, the coverage is 100%.

```
rowMeans(sapply(outci, function(x)eval_cover(obs=x)))
# (Intercept)          x1          x2          x3 
#           1           1           1           1
```

Comment: Thank you @DaveArmstrong! Now it makes sense that I had a misunderstanding about coverage probability for the bootstrap